# Alias names in output in SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a stored procedure by declaring output variables and executed successfully. But, after executing it, i do not want the so called '@' character in the output.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xyz
AS
    (@abc VARCHAR(100),
     @def VARCHAR(100) = NULL OUTPUT,
     @ghi INT = NULL OUTPUT,
     @message NVARCHAR(100) = NULL OUTPUT)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @def = def, @ghi = ghi 
    FROM
        alphabets  
    WHERE
        abc = @abc

    RETURN 1
END

BEGIN CATCH
   IF (ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205)
   BEGIN
       RAISERROR('DEADLOCK', 13, 51)
   END
   ELSE
       SELECT @message  = CONCAT (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'FALSE' )
END CATCH
```

This is my code. Now after executing this, by navigating to object explorer in SQL Server and right clicking on the procedure name and executing it, by taking input parameter value from us, it is creating the following code and executing it perfectly.

```
DECLARE @return_value INT,
        @def VARCHAR(100),
        @ghi VARCHAR(100),
        @message NVARCHAR(100)

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[xyz] '1111',
            @def = @def OUTPUT,
            @ghi = @ghi OUTPUT,
            @message = @message OUTPUT

SELECT
    @def AS '@def',
    @ghi AS '@ghi'
```

Actual result:

```
    @def   @ghi @message
    123    456
```

Desired result:

```
    def    ghi  message
    123    456
```

All I Want is to remove that '@' from the above output. Or can I use the Alias names in the procedure's output parameters it self, such that, even if some one executes it by right clicking on the procedure name in object explorer in SQL Server 2012 and execute it??

Comment: The stored procedure has no influence whatsoever on the code SSMS chooses to generate to invoke it. If you need a fixed format for the result set, either use an actual result set in the stored procedure itself rather than output parameters (`SELECT def, ghi...`) or write another sproc that does this for you, if you can't live without the convenience (?) of SSMS.

Comment: Considering you're using a `SELECT` to return the values, why not use a `SELECT` in the SP instead, and not out `OUTPUT` parameters? If you do want to use `OUTPUT` parameters, then what's wrong with simply removing the `@` from the alias?

Comment: I would like to use output parameters. I need to give an input parameter as well..

Comment: @Larnu The `select` is setting the values of the `output` parameters (`select @foo = 42`) rather than returning a result with an alias (`select foo = 42`).

Comment: To be clear: the issue you're having is that you don't like the code SSMS generates for you. You are absolutely free to rename the columns after SSMS generates the code (`SELECT @def AS [def]`), you just can't patch SSMS to do that on its own. (Well, you could, with an extension, but it's really not worth the trouble.)

Comment: That doesn't change my point though @HABO. Why set (not `SET`) the values to an `OUTPUT` parameter and `SELECT` them afterwards when you could just `SELECT` them in the SP and not use `OUTPUT` parameters at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert there are multiple teams, who will execute this procedure, they would like to do it by right clicking on the store proc and giving the input parameter value.

Comment: Then they will need to appropriately change the SQL for their wants @user1620464 . In truth, it sounds like these are people that shouldn't even have SSMS in the first place...

Comment: @Larnu I got your point. I tried it initially, but somehow, my team wants to create it in this way --- sorry cant remember why we choose this way!! :(

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why don't you just remove the @ sign from the alias? SO... SELECT @def AS 'def'

Comment: @DrDoomPDX it is automatically created by SSMS/Sql Server and most of the teams don't want to do that. They just need 'one click execution'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments/answers/ideas. Finally I resolved it by populating the values to temp table. Thanks a Lot! 
This is what I did.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xyz
AS
(@abc NVARCHAR(100),
)
BEGIN

Create #temp
(def Nvarchar(100),
 ghi Nvarchar(100),
Message Nvarchar(100)

  )


BEGIN
 insert into #temp (def, ghi)
   values  (SELECT def, ghi 
    FROM alphabets  WHERE abc = @abc)

END


BEGIN CATCH
IF (ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205)
   BEGIN
   RAISERROR('DEADLOCK', 13, 51)
   END
   ELSE
   SELECT @message  = CONCAT (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'FALSE' )
END CATCH    

Insert into #temp (message) 
values (@message)

Select * from #temp

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to do this but here you go! (like removing the '@' when aliasing it?)

```
DECLARE @title VARCHAR(250)

SET @title = '@badNaming'

SELECT LTRIM(STUFF(@title, 1, 1, ''))
```

Result: badNaming

I used the stuff function to start at the first character and replace 1 character with a space. Then used LTrim function to remove any space to the left. Hope this helped!

Comment: If I am selecting the output then this works, but am not selecting the output, its being generated by Sql server as mentioned in my query.